# magento 2 frontend error after installing an extension

Tags: magento2

Hello when i add an extension to magento 2 my frontpage disappears but at the backend everthing is fine and that extension is working. So plz let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7NHI.png)

Comment: Tried to run static deploy command?

Comment: Put code ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the start of index.php and try to find the error.

Comment: hello i have run the command but not worked.

Comment: @AnshuMishra hello i have edited index.php like this - <?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 but it is not working and now there is another line on frontend - Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /home/dealy8oi/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml on line 162 . So know plz help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please open command prompt/terminal then go to your magento root directory and run

command `php bin/magento set:upgrade`

After that run

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

to deploy static content.

Comment: hello i have run the command but not worked. Plz helpme. Thanks!

Comment: @keyur hello sir can you plz help me. i have run that command and also increased php memory limit, but nothing worked, plz help me.

Comment: Hi Rishav, can you tell me which mode you are now?

Comment: please run php bin/magento  deploy:mode:set developer to get the error.After run this command again  run php bin/magento set:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and check.

Comment: hello sir i have enabled developer mode by using above command but it not worked, there is no changes on frontend. after that i also run upgrade and content deploy command but nothing worked. sir plz help me. Thanks!

Comment: hello sir when i renamed php.ini.sample to php.ini then on frontend there is this error msg - Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /home/*******/public_html/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml on line 162.